# How to attach graph with existing parent and new child in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, disconnected-environment

How to attach graph with added child in EF Core ?

```
 private static void AttachGraphWithExistingParentNewChild()
        {
            Class class;
            using (var context = new SchoolContext())
            {
                class = context.Classes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.Contains("AA"));
            }
            class.Students.Add(new Student{Name= "Youssef" });
            using (var context = new  SchoolContext())
            {
                context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(class, e=>e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added);


            }
        }
```

---

This method will add the parent and the child and this 's not true ,i want to add just the child and let the parent Unchanged .